# I want to do "ORDER BY" before "WHERE" in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

```
SELECT card_id from logs
WHERE card_id in ('0001', '0002')
ORDER BY date desc limit 1
```

This code first selects the values that matches the list and then chooses the last row.
How can I first choose the last row from card_id and look if it matches any value in the list

Comment: By the key terms you are using, it sounds like there is some code to go along with the query?

Answer (score 2):

If you need `ORDER` before `WHERE` you must nest it in a Derived Table:

```
select *
from 
 ( SELECT card_id 
   from logs
   ORDER BY date desc limit 1      -- find the last row first
 ) as dt
WHERE card_id in ('0001', '0002')  -- and then filter
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, with a subquery that selects the last record separately from the query that looks for the specific values of card_id:

```
SELECT l.card_id
FROM logs l
WHERE l.card_id IN ('0001','0002)
AND l.card_id IN (
SELECT TOP 1 card_id FROM logs ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
```